# No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, junit

I am using JUnit 4 to test Dao Access with Spring (annotations) and JPA (hibernate). The datasource is configured through JNDI(Weblogic) with an ORacle(Backend). This persistence is configured with just the name and a RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction-type

The application context file contains notations for annotations, JPA config, transactions, and default package and configuration for annotation detection.
I am using Junit4 like so:

---

**ApplicationContext**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">  
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="workRequest"/>  
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">  
             <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.target}"/>  
             <property name="showSql" value="${database.showSql}" />  
             <property name="generateDdl" value="${database.generateDdl}" />  
         </bean>  
     </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>workRequest</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

---

**JUnit TestCase**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class AssignmentDaoTest {
      private AssignmentDao assignmentDao;
      @Test
      public void readAll() {
            assertNotNull("assignmentDao cannot be null", assignmentDao);
            List<Assignment> assignments = assignmentDao.findAll();
            assertNotNull("There are no assignments yet", assignments);
      }
}
```

regardless of what changes I make I get: 




`No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] is defined`

Any hint on what this could be. I am running the tests inside eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Your Spring context has a bean definition using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. This creates an `EntityManagerFactory`, not an `EntityManager`.

`AssignmentDao` needs to get itself wired with an `EntityManagerFactory`.

Alternatively, you can replace the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` with a `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`, which *will* create an `EntityManager` directly. However, you need to be careful with that one, it has some downsides. See that part of the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup) for a full explanation of the options.

It's confusing, because the naming conventions of JPA and Spring overlap each other, so naming these classes is a real bugger.

Comment: assignmentDao is wired by annotation, that one was inserted at the last minute for debugging, disregard. So far all examples that I have found use the EntityManagerFactory in the configuration and the EntityManager for injection. I have used it this way with Mysql w/o JUnit-Spring Integration and it worked.

Comment: @sebajb: Read the link I posted. Section 13.5.2 talks about to combine things in the way you need.

Comment: Thanks. I need to read the doc and see what suits my need. LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean seems however too limited for my requirements. I will just inject an EntityManagerFactory instead.